# Adding a game to Games Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, inno-setup

I'm trying to get a game to integrate with the Windows Games Explorer. So far I have embedded a Game Definition Format XML file as a resource in my binary and my actual Inno Setup script to integrate the the DLL to the installer looks like this:

This is what i've managed to do by now:

```
[Files]
Source: GameuxInstallHelper.dll;               DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
[Code]
const
 GIS_NOT_INSTALLED = 1;
  GIS_CURRENT_USER = 2;
 GIS_ALL_USERS = 3;
// Given a game instance GUID and path to GDF binary, registers game with Game Explorer 
procedure AddToGameExplorer( GDFBinPath: PChar; GameInstallPath: PChar; InstallScope : integer; GameGUID : GUID );
external 'AddToGameExplorerA@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Given a game instance GUID, unregisters a game from Game Explorer
function RemoveFromGameExplorer( GameGUID : GUID ) : boolean;
external 'RemoveFromGameExplorer@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Given a path to a GDF binary that has already been registered, returns a game instance GUID 
function RetrieveGUIDForApplication( GDFBinPath: PChar; var GameGUID : GUID ) : boolean; 
external 'RetrieveGUIDForApplicationA@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Creates a unique game instance GUID
function GenerateGUID( var GameGUID : GUID ) : boolean;
external 'GenerateGUID@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Register with Media Center using the data from a GDF binary
procedure RegisterWithMediaCenter( GDFBinPath : PChar; GameInstallPath : PChar; InstallScope : integer; ExePath : PChar; CommandLineArgs : PChar; UseRegisterMCEApp : boolean );
external 'RegisterWithMediaCenterA@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Unregister with Media Center
procedure UnRegisterWithMediaCenter( GameInstallPath : PChar; InstallScope : integer; strExePath : PChar; UseRegisterMCEApp : boolean );
external 'UnRegisterWithMediaCenterA@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Given a a game instance GUID, creates a task shortcut in the proper location 
procedure CreateTask( InstallScope : integer; GameInstanceGUID : GUID; SupportTask : boolean; TaskID : integer; TaskName :PChar; LaunchPath : PChar; CommandLineArgs : PChar );
external 'CreateTaskA@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// This removes all the tasks associated with a game instance GUID
// Pass in a valid GameInstance GUID that was passed to AddGame()
procedure RemoveTasks( GameInstanceGUID : GUID );
external 'RemoveTasks@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Creates the registry keys to enable rich saved games. The game still needs to use 
// the rich saved game header as defined in the documentation and support loading a
// saved game from the command line.
procedure SetupRichSavedGames( SavedGameExtension : PChar; LaunchPath : PChar; CommandLineToLaunchSavedGame : PChar);
external 'SetupRichSavedGamesA@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
// Removes the registry keys to enable rich saved games.
procedure RemoveRichSavedGames( SavedGameExtension : PChar);
external 'RemoveRichSavedGamesA@files:GameuxInstallHelper.dll stdcall';
```

However, i have two errors and i can't get past them:

```
Unknown type 'GUID'
```

and

```
Cannot import dll:C:\Users\my user\AppData\Local\Temp\a random name folder\GameuxInstallHelper.dll
```

Any ideas how to solve the errors or modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the issue with importing the DLL into the User folder - are you checking for administrative privileges?

[Section: PrivilegesRequired](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired)